# Control Panel Redirect Loop After 2.6.1 Update

Tags: control-panel, redirects, updating

I just updated from EE 2.5.1 to 2.6.1, and now I get a redirect loop error when I try to access the control panel via `admin.php`.

I cleared my cookies (and started testing in incognito mode to be safe), cleared my .htaccess file, and I added cookie variables to Master Config:

```
$env_config['cookie_domain'] = '';
$env_config['cookie_path'] = ''; 
$env_config['cookie_prefix'] = 'kg_' . ENV;
```

But that didn't fix the problem. What else should I try?

Comment: See if you were bitten by this bug: https://support.ellislab.com/bugs/detail/19378

Comment: Does this happen in Chrome only by chance?

Comment: @KevinCupp Yup, that was it! If you want to make that an actual answer I'll accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See if you were bitten by this bug: http://support.ellislab.com/bugs/detail/19378

Comment: I'm having a related issue that I've posted about here. Applied that bug fix but no go. http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/11520/cp-redirect-loop